# Select where Count of 1 field is greater than a value and count of another is less than a value

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I am trying to return all instances in a Customers table where the statustype= 'dc' then for those results, the count on FC is > 1 and the Count on Address1 is 1.

IE:

```
FC    Address1
111    abc
111    cde
432    qqq
432    qqq
```

I need the 111 FC results back because their address1 is different.  But I don't need the 432 FC results back because there is more than 1 Address for that FC

```
 SELECT *
  FROM Customers
  where FC IN( select FC from Customers where StatusType= 'dc'
  group by FC having COUNT(FC) > 1 and COUNT(Address1) < 2

)
  order by FC, Address1
```

I also tried = 1 instead of < 2

Comment: You are telling in reverse order `111 FC` has more than 1 Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the details about the FCs that have more than one unique address then this query will give you that:

```
select c.* from customers c
join (
    select FC
    from customers
    where statustype = 'dc'
    group by fc having count(distinct Address1) > 1
) a on c.FC = a.FC
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group by Address1 also.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
where FC IN( select FC from Customers where StatusType= 'dc'
group by FC, Address1 having COUNT(FC) > 1 and COUNT(Address1) < 2)
order by FC, Address1
```

Comment: It still comes up blank.  If I make the  < 2 a < 3 I get results that contain Address1 that are  < 2 and < 3  recurrences of the same address.   But the < 3 returns ~1000 results, when there is actually like 50 results that have < 2

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Distinct COUNT`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customers
WHERE  FC IN(SELECT FC
             FROM   Customers
             WHERE  StatusType = 'dc'
             GROUP  BY FC
             HAVING Count(DISTINCT Address1) > 1)
ORDER  BY FC,
          Address1
```